# Changing the onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have this

```
<img width="38" height="39" onclick="jreviews.favorite.add(this,{listing_id:2655})" class="imgFavoriteAdd" alt="Add to favorites" id="jr_favoriteImg2655" src="http://kingdomshopper.com/templates/jreviews_overrides/views/themes/default/theme_images/fav_add.png">
```

and as you can see the onclick is

```
 jreviews.favorite.add(this,{listing_id:2655})
```

I need to change the onclick to

```
jreviews.favorite.remove(this,{listing_id:2655})
```

but when i do

```
 jQuery("#jr_favoriteImg2655").attr("onclick")
 onclick(event)
```

can i do

```
 jQuery("#jr_favoriteImg2655").attr("onclick", "jreviews.favorite.add(this,{listing_id:2655})")
```

or is there a better or another way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll be lot better off if you remove the onclick attribute from your element and then do the following >

```
// Initializing >> 
var first = function () { jreviews.favorite.add(this,{listing_id:2655}) };
var second = function () { jreviews.favorite.remove(this,{listing_id:2655}) };

jQuery("#jr_favoriteImg2655").bind("click", first);
```

and then when you want to switch >

```
jQuery("#jr_favoriteImg2655").unbind("click", first);
jQuery("#jr_favoriteImg2655").bind("click", second);
```

Comment: Almost perfect; I'd suggest that you chain the `.unbind()` and `.bind()` calls together since they're using the same wrapped element.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do that (i.e. binding functions to events) is either `bind` or `click`:

```
jQuery("#jr_favoriteImg2655").click(function() {
    jreviews.favorite.remove(this,{listing_id:2655});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using inline JavaScript is not recommended, but anyway you can use a condition here to make sure you added this to favorite before or not. Something like this:

```
<img width="38" height="39" onclick="if(!jreview.favorite.exist(this)){jreviews.favorite.add(this,{listing_id:2655})}else{jreviews.favorite.remove(this,{listing_id:2655})}" class="imgFavoriteAdd" alt="Add to favorites" id="jr_favoriteImg2655" src="http://kingdomshopper.com/templates/jreviews_overrides/views/themes/default/theme_images/fav_add.png">
```

I'm not familiar with your API and `exist` is just an example